# Несколько сниппетов в прокручиваемой области

Tags: дефект, сниппеты

[Angular4 не видит файлы с сервера NET Core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/719710/178988)

Это что?

[image: Скриншот 1]
[image: Скриншот 2]
[image: Скриншот 3]
[image: Скриншот 4]

Comment: забавно, но похоже на новую фичу сниппетов

Comment: Задал вопрос на мета мете, но там пока тишина :-) Суть в 4 пробелах перед комментарием определяющем сниппет

Comment: @Grundy а ссылку добавить?

Comment: @alexolut, какую ссылку?

Comment: @Grundy, на метамету.

Comment: @Qwertiy, [вот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301199/282647)